# Capacitor Charging/Differential Equation

Tags: capacitor

[image: capacitor question]

I study 1st year electronic engineering, and my university has a policy against posting past paper solutions. I can derive the equation in part a.) however I don't understand how to complete the 2nd part. If anyone could explain what to do that would be great :)

thanks

Comment: Do you know how to express \${dv_c}\over{dt}\$?

Comment: i know that i = dq/dt, then subbing for q = cv, c(dv/dt) = i

Comment: Solve the differential equation via the integrating factor method, then compare coefficients with the required form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. just substitute Vc in the above equation. name it "eq1"
2. at t=0, Vc=0
   now you get V2-K1=K2(R2C2L+1) (L is lambda) :"eq2"
3. return to "eq1" and substitute V2-K1 to obtain an expression with only L and K2. you can factorize and solve with 2 possible solutions: L=-1/R2C2 or K2=0
4. for the first solution, return to "eq2" => K1=V2. At t=0,V=K1+K2=0=>K2=-V2
5. for the second solution (K2=0), you get Vc=V2. this is the steady state solution

Comment: my first attempt was subbing Vc into the equation, it's the next part that I'm struggling to understand

Answer (score 0):

Substitution is easy and straight forward but here is the second method : this requires you to rearrange the equation as shown and then apply integration on both sides to get the voltage across the capacitor with respect to time.

$$\frac {dv_c}{v_2-v_c}=R_2C_2 dt$$

this is the rearranged equation.

You may be able to carry on from here?

Comment: Your suggested method works and is the easy way to go, but the question is asking to solve the question by substitution and to use the expressions K1,K2 and lambda

Comment: Where was asked about substitution? @fhlb It is said that it has that form, so when you derive it using the above method you will then compare the two derived equations and find the solution

Comment: by giving the expression of the solution of the diff equation... hmmm i might be wrong but it seems they don't want him to solve the differential equation

Answer (score 0):

So you have an equation of the form:

K1 + K2e^(Lt).

What's going to happen to the capacitor after you close the switch?

What's the initial voltage? (t = 0)

What's the final voltage? (t -> infinity)

What is the time constant? (tau = RC)

The answers to the these questions should let you solve the for K1,K2,and L